# How to get mixamo character to continue falling down and not hit the ground in blender

Tags: animation, armature, transforms, axis

I have a scene where I have a mixamo character running then jumping off a building. Instead of the mixamo character jumping and hitting the ground I would like for it to actually continue falling down without hitting the ground. For some reason I managed to get it working before by moving the building up higher away from the floor axis and the character kept falling down. Now since I restarted my animation over its not working anymore. Any idea how I could get it working. Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try finding the z axis movement in the graph editor and change these values?

Comment: How about make a hole in the ground?

Answer (score 1):

"Normally" you can move the whole body with the hips bone of mixamos rigs.

So select the hip bone (delete all keyframes of z in that falling area), go to the frame where it should start falling, press I and move your timeline where the end of falling should be and move the hip bone downwards as much as you like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Chris. You've really been very helpful to me and save a lot of my time trying to figure it. You've answered my previous question that I posted as well and I am thankful for that. :)

Comment: @Alphanum3ric Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).